# JS/jQuery number increasing in for

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

According to the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wAwyR/9/), i want in each times adding new input with putting number in fields(1, 2, 3), number increasing in each one from new input adding to `name[+number increasing here+][]` in the input.

Now i have this in my code:
**[Example:](http://jsfiddle.net/wAwyR/9/)**

> if put to "field 1" number `2` we get tow new input that name it is
>   `name[0][], name[1][]`.
>  in "field 2" put number `3` we get
>   `name[0][], name[1][], name[2][]`
>  in "field 3" put number `2` we
>   get `name[0][], name[1][]`

**I want thie:**

> if put to "field 1" number `2` we get tow new input that name it is
>   `name[0][], name[1][]`
>  in "field 2" put number `3` we get
>   `name[2][], name[3][], name[4][]`
>  in "field 3" put number `2` we
>   get `name[5][], name[6][]` and etc.

Code:

```
$('input').live("keyup", function () {    
    var id = '#'+$(this).closest('b').attr('id');
    $(id+' .lee').empty();    
    var $val = $(this).val();
    for (var i = 0; i < $val; i++) {
        $(id+' .lee').append('<input type="text" name="hi['+i+'][]">');        
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to update all of the inputs on change, you could loop through all inputs after appending the elements. Just add a classname to them so you know which ones to count.

Example:

```
$('input').live("keyup", function () {    
    var id = '#'+$(this).closest('b').attr('id'),
    val = $(this).val();

    $(id+' .lee').empty();  

    for (var i = 0; i < val; i++) {
        $(id+' .lee').append('<input type="text" class="input_generated">');  
    }

    $('input.input_generated').each(function(i) {
      $(this).attr('name', 'hi[' + i + '][]');
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rHUqS/1/

Comment: If not want use from `.attr('name', 'hi[' + i + '][]');`, i want use as: `<input type="text" name="hi['+i+'][]">`, how is it?

Comment: Well, you could use jQuerys .replaceWith(), but that would be an unnecessary way to go. Although if you really want to do it then use this in the `each`-loop: `$(this).replaceWith('<input type="text" class="input_generated" name="hi[' + i + '][]" />');`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rHUqS/2/

Comment: I mean that I not have one input, I have several input. if want use it as, it is bad. 
it is better that done number increasing in for-loop: `for (var i = 0; i < val; i++) {
        $(id+' .lee').append('<input type="text" class="input_generated">');  
    }` how is for this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand or how you mean it is bad. The original code I posted works for several inputs. Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: For example, my inputs is as: `$(id+' .lee').append('<input type="text" name="how['+i+'][]"><input type="text" name="hi['+i+'][]"><input type="text" name="hello['+i+'][]"><input type="text" name="are['+i+'][]"><input type="text" name="is['+i+'][]"><input type="text" name="book['+i+'][]"><input type="text" name="calander['+i+'][]"><input type="text" name="glasses['+i+'][]">');        
    }`, it is better that done number increasing in for-loop, !? how is it?

Answer (score 0):

By using a variable outside the function, you can solve this simply.  However, it would always just increment the index numbers; if you typed the counts in in the wrong order, your indexes would be in the wrong order.  But maybe that's okay.

```
var counter = 0;
$('input').live("keyup", function () {    
    var id = '#'+$(this).closest('b').attr('id');
    $(id+' .lee').empty();    
    var val = int($(this).val());
    for (var i = counter; i < val + counter; i++) {
        $(id+' .lee').append('<input type="text" name="hi['+i+'][]">');        
    }
    counter = val + counter;
});
```

EDIT: fixed val coming through as a string not an int

Comment: Your code is bad worked, see : http://jsfiddle.net/wAwyR/10/ . please add number 2 in field 1 and number 2 in field 2. you get a lot of input no 2 input!!

Comment: This not worked: http://jsfiddle.net/wAwyR/11/ . please give me example in http://jsfiddle.net/